# Change CSS class on divs according to past time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Here I have 24 divs as time slots of an entire day, these slots have contains one single hour for booking any property.

i have 2 types of css classes here.. one is (.hour_slots_disabled) which have shown above quetion section and second one is (.hour_slots_disabled). now i want to apply disable class for past time. i.e. is the current time is 16:40 then i want to disable that 16:00 - 17:00 taged time slot. and rest upcoming time slots are available for booking

**Here is my CSS for disable those time-slots**

```
    .hour_slots_disabled
{
     height: 40px;
     width: 75px;
     cursor: not-allowed;
     background-color: #ccc;
     border-radius: 2px;
     -o-transition:.5s;
     -ms-transition:.5s;
     -moz-transition:.5s;
     -webkit-transition:.5s;
      transition:.5s;
}
```

**Here is my 24 divs as time slots**

```
<li><div class="hour_slots_available" id="12_01"><span class="hour_tag">12:00 - 01:00</span></div></li>
<li><div class="hour_slots_available" id="01_02"><span class="hour_tag">01:00 - 02:00</span></div></li>
<li><div class="hour_slots_available" id="02_03"><span class="hour_tag">02:00 - 03:00</span></div></li>
<li><div class="hour_slots_available" id="03_04"><span class="hour_tag">03:00 - 04:00</span></div></li>
<li><div class="hour_slots_available" id="04_05"><span class="hour_tag">04:00 - 05:00</span></div></li>
<li><div class="hour_slots_available" id="05_06"><span class="hour_tag">05:00 - 06:00</span></div></li>
<li><div class="hour_slots_available" id="06_07"><span class="hour_tag">06:00 - 07:00</span></div></li>
<li><div class="hour_slots_available" id="07_08"><span class="hour_tag">07:00 - 08:00</span></div></li>
<li><div class="hour_slots_available" id="08_09"><span class="hour_tag">08:00 - 09:00</span></div></li>
<li><div class="hour_slots_available" id="09_10"><span class="hour_tag">09:00 - 10:00</span></div></li>
<li><div class="hour_slots_available" id="10_11"><span class="hour_tag">10:00 - 11:00</span></div></li>
<li><div class="hour_slots_available" id="11_12"><span class="hour_tag">11:00 - 12:00</span></div></li>
<li><div class="hour_slots_available" id="12_13"><span class="hour_tag">12:00 - 13:00</span></div></li>
<li><div class="hour_slots_available" id="13_14"><span class="hour_tag">13:00 - 14:00</span></div></li>
<li><div class="hour_slots_available" id="14_15"><span class="hour_tag">14:00 - 15:00</span></div></li>
<li><div class="hour_slots_available" id="15_16"><span class="hour_tag">15:00 - 16:00</span></div></li>
<li><div class="hour_slots_available" id="16_17"><span class="hour_tag">16:00 - 17:00</span></div></li>
<li><div class="hour_slots_available" id="17_18"><span class="hour_tag">17:00 - 18:00</span></div></li>
<li><div class="hour_slots_available" id="18_19"><span class="hour_tag">18:00 - 19:00</span></div></li>
<li><div class="hour_slots_available" id="19_20"><span class="hour_tag">19:00 - 20:00</span></div></li>
<li><div class="hour_slots_available" id="20_21"><span class="hour_tag">20:00 - 21:00</span></div></li>
<li><div class="hour_slots_available" id="21_22"><span class="hour_tag">21:00 - 22:00</span></div></li>
<li><div class="hour_slots_available" id="22_23"><span class="hour_tag">22:00 - 23:00</span></div></li>
<li><div class="hour_slots_available" id="23_24"><span class="hour_tag">23:00 - 24:00</span></div></li>
```

**Here is a pic of those time-slots**

> [image]

Comment: What you need exactly? Just the code to change the css class?

Comment: i have 2 types css classes here.. one is (.hour_slots_disabled) which have shown above quetion section and second one is (.hour_slots_disabled). now i want to apply disable class for past time. i.e. is the current time is 16:40 then i want to disable that 16:00 - 17:00 taged time slot. and rest upcoming time slots are available for booking

Comment: Okay, I understood, you can check my answer bellow and see if it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to retrive the first hour of your `div#id` to compare with current hour and then disable the past time-slots:

```
function addZero(i) {
    if (i < 10) {
       i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}

var date = new Date();
var hour = addZero(date.getHours()); //Get current hour

$('ul li').each(function(){
    var div_hour = $('ul li div.hour_slots_available').attr('id');
    div_hour = div_hour.substring(0, 2); //Get only the start hour on your div#id

   if(div_hour <= hour){
      //Remove all time-slots where slot hour is past or equal to current hour
      $('li div[id^='+ div_hour +']').removeClass('hour_slots_available');
      $('li div[id^='+ div_hour +']').addClass('hour_slots_disabled');
   }
});
```

Comment: got it, i'll check it.

Comment: @AshishVyas It's missing something because the hour is get without the zero, but I'll change it right away

Comment: previous one is not working. now i'll try with your new code

Comment: It should work now :) Since your `div#id` has a zero for the hours between 0 and 10, and the `getHours()` function don't put zeros at left, it has to be added the zero to it to stay equal with your `div#id`

Comment: please just tell me one thing. where can  i place this entire function ? at the bottom of entire page or ajax responce ?

Comment: It depends on how you structured your code.. Does your time-slots only appear by ajax after the user select the arrivée date and invité? If that's so then you should place it on the ajax.. If not, you can try and place it at the bottom of the page.. Also be careful with other lists you might have, so give this time-slots list a class to their `ul` and put that class in each call to the `li` or `div`

Comment: Anything is not working..! Anyways, Thanks @JuOliveira for kind support :)

Comment: Actually, i have 24 time slots that are available but i generate a ajax for disable booked time slots which are come from database. now i put following code:  $('.hour_slots_disabled').removeClass('hour_slots_disabled').addClass('hour_slots_available'); just above from $.each function which is use for disable booked slots one by one

Comment: this statement returns undifined: var div_hour = $('li div').attr('id');

Comment: okkk thank you :) now problem solved. see my solved Answer :)

Comment: Sorry @AshishVyas I was out for lunch! xD One single line that ruined everything, but very well done, you're able to solve it! :) That's the way to go :) And you're welcome ^^

Comment: No worries @JuOliveira , Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
function addZero(i) {
                    if (i < 10) {
                       i = "0" + i;
                    }
                    return i;
                }

                var d = new Date();
             var n = addZero(d.getHours());

                $('ul li').each(function(){
                    var div_hour = $('ul li div.hour_slots_available').attr('id');

                    div_hour = div_hour.substring(0, 2); //Get only the start hour on your div#id
                   if(div_hour <= n){
                      //Remove all time-slots where slot hour is past or equal to current hour
                      $('li div[id^='+ div_hour +']').removeClass('hour_slots_available');
                      $('li div[id^='+ div_hour +']').addClass('hour_slots_disabled');
                   }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

For changing class of any `<div>` you can use Javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      var d = new Date();
      var n = d.getHours();

  if($n >= 09)
   {
     $("#09_10").removeClass("hour_slots_available");
     $("#09_10").addClass("hour_slots_disabled");
   }
   });
```

Here I've displayed you only for one specific `div` but same way you can implement your own logic.

Comment: i already know it my friend. but i just want to disable those divs which have contains past time

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you expect.

```
var d = new Date(); // for now    

var slots = $("#[ulid] li"); // select all your li by your parent id
$.each(slots,function(){
var currentSlotByHr = parseInt($(this + " div").attr('id').splt("_")[0]);
if(currentSlotByHr <= d.getHours())
{
$(this + " div").addClass("hour_slots_disabled");
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = new Date();
var h = d.getHours();

$('li').each(function(){
    $('li div:lt(' + h + ')' ).addClass('hour_slots_disabled');
})
```